# how can i display images using grid

Tags: asp.net

How to display images in a grid in asp.net .These images are stored in a  folder in project directory(Images).I want to show these images in grid and show images description from database .Description should show just under the image.please help

Answer (score 2):

Use a [template field](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs).

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">           
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img src='<%# "/images/" + Eval("FileName") %>' width="" height="" />
                <br />
                <p>Eval("Description")</p>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```